# Defining array type issue in C

Tags: c, arrays, physics

I'm trying to model a simple voltage distribution across a wire in C (university physics problem). I'm having trouble with setting the boundary conditions using arrays, I need to set the edges of the wire (imagine the boundaries of a 2d grid) to 0. I also need to set two squares (wire cores inside grid) to 10 and -10 respectively.

The programming problem I'm having is I get the error: incompatible types when assigning to type `double[30][15]` from type `int`, I've set the array (2d grid) as a 30*15 double so I'm not sure why its doing this?

This is me defining the array and counters:

```
int i,j,h;
double Vnew[30][15],Vold[30][15];
```

and this is what how I'm trying to set the boundary conditions (only bit where I'm getting this error)

```
if ((i == 0 || 30) && j==j){Vnew=0;}
if ((j == 0 || 15) && i==i){Vnew=0;}
if ((6<=i<=9) && (6<=j<=9)){Vnew=-10;}
if ((21<=i<=24) && (6<=j<=9)){Vnew=10;}
```

Comment: seems you need to improve your basic skills in C

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement along with what you want to accomplish. Learn [ask]. I'm not sure you know yourself what you want to do or how to. No offence.

Comment: Start by reading [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).

Comment: A test like `i == 0 || 30` doesn't make sense.  This groups as `(i == 0) || 30`.  It will always be true (non-zero), since regardless of the value of `i`, 30 is always non-zero.  You probably meant `i == 0 || i == 30`.  Similarly for `j`.  Your attempted 3-way tests won't work either.  Instead of `6<=i<=9`, you need to write `6<=i && i<=9`.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect `Vnew=-10` to do?  It does not make any sense (logically or otherwise) to assign 1 integer to 450 doubles.  If you meant `Vnew[0][0] = -10;` then write that.

Answer (score 2):

> if ((i == 0 || 30) && j==j){Vnew=0;}

First this: `|| 30` doesn't do what you think it does (what it does is 30 will always evaluate to true as it is non zero),
it should be probably `i == 0 || i == 30`

Also this:

```
Vnew=0;
```

you can't assign value to array like this. You need to use an index (e.g. `Vnew[i][j]=..`). Please look up basics on how to use arrays in C.

This

```
(6<=i<=9)
```

is also not good, need to use `6<=i && i<=9`

Comment: More than sufficient, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to assign

```
Vnew[i][j] = ...
```

and

```
Vold[i][j] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array of struct might work to simplify notation.  For example...

```
typedef struct {
    double new;
    double old;
}V;

V v[30][15];

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<15;j++)
        {
            if(((i==0)||(i==29)) && ((j==0)||(j==14)))
            {
                v[i][j].new=0;
            }
            ...// and so on.
```

Note also, the way that logical operator && and || are used.
Also, array indexes start at 0 and end at size of the array - 1.
For example: given

```
int array[4][3];
```

In a nested for loop, using int i, j, the indexes would go from 0 to 3 and 0 to 2 respectively to loop through the array. (In your code example, you show your indexes going to the size of the arrays, 30 and 15.)